# GetThreadContext return 87 on win7 x64

Tags: c++, windows-7-x64

I am trying to run this code in a function, but GetThreadContext return error:87

```
CONTEXT cxt;
SuspendThread(hThread);

ZeroMemory(&cxt, sizeof(cxt));
cxt.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
if (!GetThreadContext(hThread, &cxt)) {
    printf("GetThreadContext getlasterror: %d", GetLastError());
    goto finish;
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx 87 (0x57) - The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: You ought to check the return value of SuspendThread(), earliest way to find out that your hThread argument isn't valid.  The thread might not be running anymore.

Comment: i know 87 means: "The parameter is incorrect", when i debug this code, all of them is wok except `GetThreadContext`, and the `hThread` is win32 application

Comment: If I remember rightly, a 32-bit process can't use GetThreadContext if the target is a 64-bit thread.  Have you built your code as a 64-bit application?

Comment: no, i don't have source code, i only have 32-bit exe, and i can start this 32-bit exe on 64-bit platform by double click it. should i use another API instead of `GetThreadContext` ? thanks